# Computing degree of hom sheaf of coherent sheaves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, coherent-sheaves

Let $C$ be complex projective curve (Cohen-Macaulay at least). Let $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ be coherent sheaves on $C$.

**Is there any way to express the degree of $\underline{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_C}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})$ in terms of the degrees of $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$?**

For locally free sheaves this is obvious but I couldn't prove a generalization to the coherent case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the degree may depend not only on the degrees (and ranks) of $F$ and $G$. For instance, let $C$ be a smooth curve, $F = O_x$ and $G = O_y$. Then 
$$
\mathcal{H}om(F,G) = 
\begin{cases}
O_x, & \text{if $x = y$},\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and its degree is 1 in the first case and 0 in the other, while the degree of $F$ and $G$ is equal to 1 (and rank equals 0) in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do you know what happens in the specific case where $C\subset \mathbb{P}^n$, $F=\det \mathcal{N}$ the determinant of the normal sheaf and $G = \omega_{\mathbb{P}^n}|_C$ is the restriction of the canonical sheaf?

Comment: How bad is your curve and how do you define the normal sheaf?

Comment: It can be Gorenstein. I know that in local complete intersection the normal sheaf is well behaved, however I'm a bit lost in a more general setting.

Comment: So, how do you define the normal sheaf and its determinant?

Comment: The normal sheaf is defined $(I/I^2)^\ast$ where $I$ is the sheaf of ideals. And I just realized that I do not know how to  define the determinant as I do not know is a locally free resolution of the normal sheaf exists

Comment: That was the point.

Comment: Any idea on how to define that?

Comment: That depends on your purpose.